# How to create/write/edit files on a server using JavaScript and Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't get this to work. What I want to do: Write text to the file example.txt on my server.

```
var text = "Example;Example;Example";

function saveToTxt(text)
{
  //Code which saves text to file
}
```

As far as I know, I have to use some kind of Ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Can someone give me an example on how to do this are any alternatives?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say server, what server you mean? What is the server side language you are using?

Comment: I am using Apache to run this on my computer. As language, I intend to use php together with ajax.

Comment: Then you need php code that will get text from Ajax call and save it as text?

Comment: Have you tried anything in php yet to do that?

Comment: If not, you need to try something then we can fix your code.

Comment: I don't want the page to refresh in order to do that. That is the problem I have.

Comment: Send data to php on server and write to file there

Answer (score 0):

This post talk about how to save and write file into server using js and php.
([Saving a text file on server using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722765/saving-a-text-file-on-server-using-javascript)).

This is another post where you can edit your file with php.([How to edit/update a txt file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865548/how-to-edit-update-a-txt-file-with-php))

Hope this helps